# Extrema of arbitrary smooth functions in $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, maxima-minima, smooth-functions

This isn't a very precisely worded question, but here goes:

Is there a sense in which generic smooth functions in $L^2$ will have multiple maxima?

Do arbitrary smooth functions in $L^2$ almost always have an arbitrarily large number of maxima?

These seems intuitively true to me, but I have no idea how I would go about showing them, or really even in what sense of genericity they are true.
Are there additional/other nontrivial constraints I could impose on the function to make these statements true/easier to show?

Comment: The localized non-positive negatively peaked function would have one minima and no maxima. For the function $f(x)=0$ I would think it has no maxima or minima. I guess I essentially want $f'(x)=0$ but $d^n f(x)/dx^n \neq 0$ for some $n$. I'm essentially looking for local maxima.

Comment: Could you add a bit more clarity? Take something highly peaked and localized- it has one maximum. Take something localized, non-positive, and negatively peaked, such as $-e^{-x^2}$. This has no maxima. Heck, take the function 0. So, I'm not entirely sure what you mean

Comment: For what I originally wrote, I meant something which was zero outside of a compact set. Just like with zero, this has infinitely many maxima by definition. I changed it, though, for something more interesting. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima This defines local maxima, and you can see that $0$ has infinitely many.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that the zero function is normally considered to have infinitely many local maxima and minima. What I'm interested in are functions where the local maxima has a value that is strictly larger than other values in a small neighborhood. Which I think is what $f'(x)=0$ but $d^n f(x)/dx^n \neq 0$ would imply.

Comment: But yes, in that sense a unimodal function like a gaussian would not satisfy what I want. Is there a sense in which such unimodal functions are "rare"?

Comment: This might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764641/linearspan-of-gaussians-dense-in-schwartz-space